# How to select nested elements using standard CSS selectors (nth-of-type or nth-child) for Selenium?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How would I select the paragraph tag for B (or C), using the nth-child or nth-of-type? I am using the Selenium WebDriver.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <p class="myClass">A</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p class="myClass">B</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p class="myClass">C</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Background: I'm trying to automate testing using Selenium WebDriver, and since nth(i) only works in the IDE, I'm trying to determine how to grab the element using standard CSS selectors.

When selecting the first element, it works, but not when selecting the nth element. I assume this is due to the nesting.
This does not work:
.myClass:nth-of-type(2) (locater not found, according to the Selenium IDE)
.myClass:nth-child(2)  (locater not found, according to the Selenium IDE)

Comment: Works fine for me, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2QmE/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for Selenium WebDriver:

```
String css = ".myClass";
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(css));
WebElement e = list.get(n);
```

It's not ideal, but it works.

Comment: What is `n` supposed to be?

Comment: `n` is the index of the element you want to retrieve from the list of elements

Comment: @BoltClock - What ragamufin said.

Answer (score 1):

Would not the :contains() css selector function for you?

```
driver.FindElements(By.cssSelector("p.myClass:contains('B')"));
```

Answer: No, because :contains() is a JQuery pseudo-function.

If you are using C#, import the SizSelCsZzz for JQuery functionality.  Then you can do:
`driver.FindElements(new ByJQuery.ByJQuerySelector("p.myClass:contains('B')", true));`

Also, for nth-child, it is also a JQuery pseudo-function.  Similarly:

```
using SizSelCsZzz;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
   public class YourClass
   {
      By selectB = new ByJQuery.ByJQuerySelector("p.myClass:nth-child(2)", true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to select B:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td p {/*your styles here */}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know selenium (so this may be of no use), but if you need to use standard CSS selectors you could select 'C' like this:

```
table tr + tr + tr > td > p {color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

p tag has not sibling elements since they are on diferent columns. Try to use nth-child pseudo  class on the tr tag. For example, to change background of odd rows:

```
table tr:nth(odd){
    background-color: #color-code;
}
```